# Loading Laravel Chart consoletvs/charts:7.*

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, chart.js

I am new to laravel charts.I thought following the documentation to make a sample chart will be a stepping stone. Having followed the documentation form adding the package into my project using `composer require consoletvs/charts:7.*` and publishing the configuration file by running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts` and then creating a new chart with the command: `php artisan make:chart SampleChart` a SampleChart was made under **App\Chart**

In the SampleChart class i made the following chart configuration

```
 public ?string $name = 'SampleChart';
  public ?string $routeName = 'SampleChart';
   public ?array $middlewares = ['auth'];
```

I then manually register using the **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider** with the code as stated from the documentation

```
 public function boot(Charts $charts)
        {
            $charts->register([
                \App\Charts\SampleChart::class
            ]);
        }
```

On rendering the chart in my views; I put in the following code

```
<div id="chart" style="height: 300px;">    </div>
<!-- Charting library -->
 
<script src="{{ asset('js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>//downloaded from https://unpkg.com/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js
<!-- Chartisan -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/chartisan_chartjs.js') }}">
</script> //downloaded from https://unpkg.com/@chartisan/echarts/dist/chartisan_echarts.js
<!-- Your application script -->
<script>
  const chart = new Chartisan({
    el: '#chart',
    url: "@chart('SampleChart')",
    loader: {
        color: '#222',
        size: [30, 30],
        type: 'bar',
        textColor: '#000',
        text: 'Loading some chart data...',
    },
  });
</script>
```

the output is a flex item with a caption "Loading some chart data... " and nothing shows. Am Stucked

I used the tutorial form https://dev.to/arielmejiadev/use-laravel-charts-in-laravel-5bbm and https://izwebtechnologies.com/2019/06/03/how-to-create-charts-in-laravel/ but none was able to made me accomplish having a chart. though the two tutorial links are for chart6.* i later read the two have different approaches to chart design.
I am Usning **Laravel7** and **charts:7.***

Comment: Did you figure it out? If you did I'm sure many people will upvote your answer (seeing how tutorials are lacking)

Comment: It has taking a toll of my time then and i had to switch. But will sure look into it and made a tutorial for it

Answer (score 3):

i am the author.

Some of the issues may be releated to laravel charts, and others to chartisan. I am doing my best to keep everybody happy here but seems people are not happy with the docs.

I am creating an example page with all sorts of examples on chartisan's page.

Remember laravel charts now only acts as a wrapper around chartisan's php package.

Its such a big project for a single person and i like to see constructive feedback.

What exacly isn't clear from the chartisan docs?

Comment: I must first commend on your effort. Your work is really great and wish you more success. The problem of the documentation of which I faced was the way the explanations where made with no clear examples. Creating the example page I believe will solve 90% of things that were not very clear especially the configuration aspect of the your documentation. I had to read and read the documentation without seeing a visible example to understand a substantial part of it. Chart6. * has a lot of examples which chart 7* doesn't

Comment: everything on the chartisan docs are not detailed, ranging from hooks, also it would be preferable if we can specify the type of chart we want from the backend directly also the colors from backend rather than coming to the front end

Comment: You are doing a great job. Can you update the progress of v8 as you promised in 2022 on GitHub https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts/issues/1#issuecomment-1208550258

Answer (score 1):

try to run without `public ?array $middlewares = ['auth'];` set.
just `public ?array $middlewares = [];`

^^^^^^^^^^ **this is how I used with Laravel package** ^^^^^^^^^^

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  **This is how I use now** vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

After some time using the ConsoleTV/Charts I decided not to use it like Laravel package.
I get rid of any use of it and use the javascript version only.

To get the data I did this:

Create a controller named whatever you want and put a function like this:

```
    public function chartSample1()
    {
        $data = array(
            "chart" => array(
                "labels" => ["First", "Second", "Third"]
            ),
            "datasets" => array(
                array("name" => "Sample 1", "values" => array(10, 3, 7)),
                array("name" => "Sample 2", "values" => array(1, 6, 2)),
            )
        );

        return $data;
    }
```

On the "**routes/web.php**" added:

```
Route::get('/chartSample1', 'MyChartController@chartSample1')->name('chartSample1');
```

And on the page:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>

                        <div id="chart" style="height: 300px;"></div>

                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                        <div id="chart2" style="height: 300px;"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                        <div id="chart3" style="height: 300px;"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{{-- This script has more features --}}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chartisan/chartjs/dist/chartisan_chartjs.js"></script>

{{-- 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chartisan/echarts/dist/chartisan_echarts.js"></script> 
--}}

</script>
<script>
    const chart = new Chartisan({
        el: '#chart',
        url: "{{ route('chartSample1') }}",
        hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
        .colors(['#ECC94B', '#4299E1'])
        .legend()
        loader: {
            color: '#ff00ff',
            size: [30, 30],
            type: 'bar',
            textColor: '#11ff00',
            text: 'Loading some chart data...',
        }
    });
    
    const chart2 = new Chartisan({
        el: '#chart2',
        data: {
            chart: { "labels": ["First", "Second", "Third"] },
            datasets: [
                { "name": "Sample 1", "values": [10, 3, 7] },
                { "name": "Sample 2", "values": [5, 6, 2] }
            ],
        },
        hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
            .colors(['#ECC94B', '#4299E1', '#AAEE11'])
            .legend({ position: 'left' })
            .beginAtZero()
            .datasets([{ type: 'line', fill: false }, 'bar']),
    });

    const chart3 = new Chartisan({
        el: '#chart3',
        data: {
            chart: { "labels": ["First", "Second", "Third"] },
            datasets: [
                { "name": "Sample 1", "values": [10, 3, 7] },
            ],
        },
        hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
            .colors(['#ECC94B', '#4299E1', '#AAEE11'])
            .datasets([{ type: 'pie', fill: true }, 'pie']),
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I did but nothing changed. I can only access that page when I logged in.

Comment: I would want a sample steps to see how to make charts using charts 7*

Comment: I did the same example and like you didn`t work even logged in.
When I removed the middleware attribute from the SampleChart.php it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. I made a little mistake. It really worked. But the Chart disappears in a second. How do i go about that

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I've been able to solve it. The configuration in your chart class is not compulsory. You can choose to ignore them.

Your render url is also wrong. It is supposed to be in snake case:

```
//SampleChart will be
@chart('sample_chart')

//PostData will be
@chart('post_data')
```

If you specified the route in your Chart class, you will have to use that: `@chart('your_route')`. If you don't know your route, use the `php artisan route:list -c` command to check.

If you want to specify the type of chart, you have to use hooks.

I ran into a bit of an issue myself. Everything Works for line chart and bar chart, but i can't present a pie chart. The Doughnut is also not working.

Comment: My current Problem is that my chart disappears after few seconds of appearing. There is also no problem shown in the console.  Do you know what causes charts to disappear? Have you come across this problem?